# JIRA XML Export contains HTML characters

Tags: c#, xml, jira

I am trying to parse xml export from JIRA. This is an example: 
https://jira.atlassian.com/si/jira.issueviews:issue-xml/DEMO-4778/DEMO-4778.xml
When I open it in browser and right click -> save as -> xml then everything is as expected. But when I try to use c# to get that content there is a problem with nodes like this:

```
<description>
<p>Go to the Browser <br/> Open the application<br/> Log In to the page <br/> Click on Categories button<br/> Click on Add button <br/> Not able to add any Category on Categories table <br/> Given me Error Message </p>
</description>
```

The problem is that they contain html characters inside and are not converted in c# world characters. For example: `<br/>` is just escaped to be **& lt;br/& gt;** instead of being treated as newline. This problem doesn't exist when I download it with my browser and load it from file, what is the difference?

This is my code:

```
 WebRequest request = WebRequest.CreateHttp("https://jira.atlassian.com/si/jira.issueviews:issue-xml/DEMO-4778/DEMO-4778.xml");

                using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        using (StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(stream))
                        {
                            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(rss));
                            var rss =(rss)serializer.Deserialize(objReader);
                            var desc = rss.channel.item.description.Text[0];

                        }

                    }
                }
```

And this is a desc variable content:

```
<p>Go to the Browser <br/>
Open the application<br/>
Log In to the page <br/>
Click on Categories button<br/>
Click on Add button <br/>
Not able to add any Category on Categories table <br/>
Given me Error Message </p>
```

And why JIRA exports contain html tags inside text?
I guess what I am doing is getting a webpage instead of it's content. What is done behind the scenes of "Save as xml" in browser?

Comment: What I get with browsers is the same with the code..... It is an rss xml....

Comment: You are right, I must have confused something, I will check it on monday and update my question. Thanks